# how to decide the longest continuous sequence in a long sequence in r

Tags: r, data.table

I have a sequence as the toy example.
how can I decide the longest continuous sub-sequence?
for now, i can find where the breaking points are, how can I get the values?

```
DT <- data.table(X = c(3:7, 16:18, 22:29, 31:36))
DT[,Y:=(shift(.SD,type = "lag", fill = -1))][,Y:= Y-X]
with(DT, which(Y !=-1))
```

what I hope to find is the value of the subquence, in this case, shall be `c(22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29)`

Comment: I'm not sure the output you're expecting? By any chance is `DT[with(DT, which(Y !=-1)),]` what you want?

Comment: How do you want the result? Check `seqle` from the "cgwtools" package, perhaps.

Comment: For reference, the idea I had in mind was something like `library(cgwtools); inverse.seqle(setDT(seqle(DT$X))[lengths == max(lengths)])` or `library(cgwtools); inverse.seqle(setDT(seqle(DT$X))[which.max(lengths)])` depending on how you wanted to deal with multiple longest sequences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option which should be faster when data gets big:

```
DT[DT[, {
    rl <- cumsum(c(1L, diff(X)>1L))
    rw <- rowid(rl)
    .I[rl==rl[which.max(rw)]]}]]
```

timing code:

```
set.seed(0L)
nr <- 1e7
ngap <- nr/2
DT <- data.table(X=sample(nr, ngap))
setorder(DT, X)

mtd0 <- function() {
    DT[, length := .N, by = cumsum(c(1, diff(X) != 1))][length == max(length), X]
}

mtd1 <- function() {
    ls <- split(DT$X, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(DT$X) != 1)))
    DT[X %in% ls[[which.max(lengths(ls))]], X]
}

mtd2 <- function() {
    DT[DT[, {
        rl <- cumsum(c(1L, diff(X)>1L))
        rw <- rowid(rl)
        .I[rl==rl[which.max(rw)]]}], X]
}

bench::mark(mtd0(), mtd1(), mtd2(), check=FALSE)
```

output:

```
> mtd0()
[1] 4622514 4622515 4622516 4622517 4622518 4622519 4622520 4622521 4622522 4622523 4622524 4622525 4622526 4622527 4622528 4622529 4622530 4622531 4622532
[20] 4622533 4622534 4622535 8390357 8390358 8390359 8390360 8390361 8390362 8390363 8390364 8390365 8390366 8390367 8390368 8390369 8390370 8390371 8390372
[39] 8390373 8390374 8390375 8390376 8390377 8390378
> mtd1()
[1] 4622514 4622515 4622516 4622517 4622518 4622519 4622520 4622521 4622522 4622523 4622524 4622525 4622526 4622527 4622528 4622529 4622530 4622531 4622532
[20] 4622533 4622534 4622535
> mtd2()
[1] 4622514 4622515 4622516 4622517 4622518 4622519 4622520 4622521 4622522 4622523 4622524 4622525 4622526 4622527 4622528 4622529 4622530 4622531 4622532
[20] 4622533 4622534 4622535
```

timings:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 13
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result     memory                time     gc              
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>     <list>                <list>   <list>          
1 mtd0()        1.34s    1.34s     0.747     363MB     1.49     1     2      1.34s <int [44]> <df[,3] [42 x 3]>     <bch:tm> <tibble [1 x 3]>
2 mtd1()        2.13s    2.13s     0.470     548MB     1.88     1     4      2.13s <int [22]> <df[,3] [34,671 x 3]> <bch:tm> <tibble [1 x 3]>
3 mtd2()     642.91ms 642.91ms     1.56      343MB     4.67     1     3   642.91ms <int [22]> <df[,3] [29 x 3]>     <bch:tm> <tibble [1 x 3]>
```

Comment: quite inspiring. It seems that the `[,{}]' creates an independent namespace for the process which is more efficient than computing on the fly. Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure what is your expected output but here we add length of each sequence in the `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
DT[, length := .N, by = cumsum(c(1, diff(X) != 1))]

DT
#     X length
# 1:  3      5
# 2:  4      5
# 3:  5      5
# 4:  6      5
# 5:  7      5
# 6: 16      3
# 7: 17      3
# 8: 18      3
# 9: 22      8
#10: 23      8
#11: 24      8
#12: 25      8
#13: 26      8
#14: 27      8
#15: 28      8
#16: 29      8
#17: 31      6
#18: 32      6
#19: 33      6
#20: 34      6
#21: 35      6
#22: 36      6
#     X length
```

and then if you want to extract only max values, we can do

```
DT[length == max(length), ]

#    X length
#1: 22      8
#2: 23      8
#3: 24      8
#4: 25      8
#5: 26      8
#6: 27      8
#7: 28      8
#8: 29      8
```

Answer (score 3):

To find the longest sequence and what it is ...

```
ls <- split(DT$X, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(DT$X) != 1)))
ls[[which.max(lengths(ls))]]
```

And identifying them ...

```
DT[X %in% ls[[which.max(lengths(ls))]], match := TRUE]

     X  Y match
 1:  3 -1    NA
 2:  4  3    NA
 3:  5  4    NA
 4:  6  5    NA
 5:  7  6    NA
 6: 16  7    NA
 7: 17 16    NA
 8: 18 17    NA
 9: 22 18  TRUE
10: 23 22  TRUE
11: 24 23  TRUE
12: 25 24  TRUE
13: 26 25  TRUE
14: 27 26  TRUE
15: 28 27  TRUE
16: 29 28  TRUE
17: 31 29    NA
18: 32 31    NA
19: 33 32    NA
20: 34 33    NA
21: 35 34    NA
22: 36 35    NA
     X  Y match
```

Comment: really a smart way!